# Easy2Boot not working with a exfat format

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, fat32, exfat

I am triying to multiboot a USB flash drive using Easy2Boot and it says:

> You can use FAT32 or NTFS (and with a few limitations an exFAT or ext2 formatted drive)

But when I launch

> \Easy2Boot_v1.40_DPMS_ISO\docs\Make_E2B_USB_Drive\Make_E2B_USB_Drive.cmd

It only gives a ntfs and a fat32 option. How do I get it to work with exfat? THE FLASHDRIVE MUST BE EXFAT. I can use a alternative tool if necessary Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RMPrepUSB to prepare the USB drive. Instructions are on the [website.](http://www.easy2boot.com/make-an-easy2boot-usb-drive/make-and-e2b-usb-drive-using-rmprepusb/)
Why do you need to use exFAT?

Comment: @09stephenb - I guess you are using exFAT as its readable across OSes?